# Build variable $(Build.SourceBranch) is empty

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I am using a script to download the build solution files when a build is made using TFS2018. When I queue a build manually using the admin website the build variable $(Build.SourceBranch) is sometimes empty.

I need this build variable to be able to fetch the solution files for the currently built solution using the TFS2018 API.

Is this a bug? Can I fix this when I create the build definition using the TFS API?

Comment: Why are you scripting the synchronization of the code? The build system does this automatically.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann I am using a script to launch a program that downloads the built solution each time a build happends. This program extracts the files and creates a dependency graph (e.g. project relations, database used) afterwards this can be visualized by product owners and programmers. Anyway, it's a bit strange to me that it's not possible to obtain consistently the source path of the currently built solution.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for source control?

Comment: I am using TFVC for source control!

Comment: Hi @DanielMann is it possible to obtain the source path from vsts using the API?

Comment: Are you sure you use the right syntax? In PowerShell or cmd one has to use a different notation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

Comment: Hi @bergmeister yes I am sure the syntax works for some of the solutions I am building. But some don’t work because it’s missing.

Comment: @doorman Can you show the script to download solution files? And what's your build definition?